# Criando array multidimensional a partir de query a BD MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, dropdown, array-multidimensional

Tenho o seguinte problema:

Tenho uma tabela num banco de dados MySQL e em um trecho do código eu preciso fazer com que o conteúdo recuperado por uma query feita a este banco seja armazenada em um array multidimensional/matriz em php. Os valores das duas colunas consultadas estão relacionadas e eu não consigo imaginar em outra maneira de manter a relação entre os itens de maneira prática sem que estejam armazenados em uma variável de estrutura semelhante à tabela do banco de dados (no caso, o array multidimensional).

**TL;DR;** Quero armazenar o conteúdo de duas colunas de uma tabela SQL em um array multidimensional, de modo que eu consiga acessar o array com

```
'array["valor1_da_tabela"]= "valor1,valor2,valor3,..."
 array["valor2_da_tabela"]= "valor1,valor2,valor3,..."
 array["valor3_da_tabela"]= "valor1,valor2,valor3,..." 
'
```

Detalhe: sugestões de solução devem ser feitas usando PDO. Tudo isto é para poder fazer um esquema de combobox/dropdown em javascript em cascata em uma página do portal. E os itens destes combobox/dropdown são todos valores armazenados nesta tabela SQL. O primeiro funciona tranquilo. Já o segundo que depende do que foi selecionado no primeiro não está saindo por causa  da ordem de execução dos códigos client e server side. Preciso armazenar estas duas colunas inteiras com valores string para facilitar a tarefa de implementação dos combobox/dropdown em cascata dinâmicos. Se tiverem sugestões quanto a isso, também agradeço.

Agradeço a atenção dos senhores.

EDIT: Este é um trecho de uma parte do projeto que faz algo parecido só que apenas para uma coluna. O que eu tentei fazer foi adaptar este trecho para atender a minha necessidade de criar um array multidimensional ao invés de um array comum.

```
<?php 
    ini_set('default_charset','UTF-8');
    require("../dbconnect.inc.php");
    $vet = array();
    $assunto = array();
    $jsArray = "";
    $sql = "SELECT distinct assunto
                FROM arquivos";

    $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute();
    $vet = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    foreach($vet as $vet_assunto){
    array_push($assunto, $vet_assunto['assunto']);
}       
    for($i=0;$i<sizeof($assunto);$i++){
    $jsArray = $jsArray . $assunto[$i] . ",";
    }
    $jsArray = chop($jsArray, ","); 
    require("../dbdisconnect.inc.php");     
?>

<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">

    var jsStrArray = "<?php echo $jsArray; ?>";
    var listaAs = jsStrArray.split(",");

        $(document).ready(function() {     

            $.each(listaAs, function(i, val){
            var content = val;          
            $('#painel').append('<a href="aulaView.php?assunto='
                                + content   
                                + '"><div class="tile"><p class="asTitle"><b>' 
                                + content 
                                +'</b></p></div></a>');
            });

           $(".tile").hover( function(){
                $(this).css({'border':'3px solid #007CFF','box-shadow':'2px 2px 7px #00B2FF'});
           }, 
            function(){
                $(this).css({'border':'3px solid #151515','box-shadow':'2px 2px 7px #000000'});
            });
        });
</script>
```

Este trecho é uma das tentativas:

```
        $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->execute();
        $vet = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        foreach($vet as $vet_assunto){
        array_push($assunto['assunto'], $vet_assunto['assunto']);   
        array_push($assunto['assunto']['aula'], $vet_assunto['aula']);  
    }

        require("../dbdisconnect.inc.php");     
    ?>
```

Exemplo das duas colunas em questão na tabela do banco de dados:

```
Assunto|aula

teste1 | 1
teste1 | 2
teste2 | 1
teste2 | 2
teste2 | 3
```

E eu gostaria que no array ficasse organizado da seguinte maneira:

```
                  Output
   array[teste1]= {1,2}
   array[teste2]= {1,2,3}

array[teste1][1]= {2}
array[teste2][2]= {3}
```

Comment: O que você já tentou fazer?

Comment: Basicamente, tentei passar o conteúdo usando array_push() e foreach. Provavelmente eu estou usando a sintaxe de modo errado. Não tenho muita experiência com php ainda. Se quiser eu boto uma das minhas tentativas de código aqui, mas está tudo errado. Não sei em que isso iria ajudar.

Comment: É sempre importante que você poste o que já tem feito, pois mostra que você de alguma forma tentou mas não conseguiu resolver, e não quer o código inteiro pronto. Poste ai, mesmo que esteja errado, a galera irá mostrar onde você deve alterar e o que fazer para que ele funcione. :)

Comment: Sua pergunta não deixa muito claro o formato dos dados que você precisa. Tem muitas maneiras de se resolver este problema, mas depende do conteúdo da tabela. Além do código, seria legal por um exemplo real do tipo de dados que você vai armazenar. Uma possibilidade é guardar num campo texto os dados de cada linha assim: `dado1|dado2|dado3` e recuperar cada linha com `explode`. Se você puder por exemplos reais do que vai ser armazenado, aumenta a chance de ter respostas boas.

Comment: Ficou um pouco mais claro?

Comment: Bom... vou tentar ver se consigo resolver usando explode mais tarde... por enquanto estou contornando usando campos de texto, mas não é o ideal. Valeu pela dica, Bacco.